# Storage multipart upload with custom metadata not adding metadata

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, multipart

I'm constructing a `multipart/related` upload request, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload), with some custom object metadata in the request body. The upload is successful but the custom metadata fields are not being set.

The request body looks like:

```
--===============5679188666781658153==
Content-Type: application/json; -charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0

{"x-goog-meta-local-path": "./images/02-05-2017/2017-02-05T14:33:30.364112.jpg", "x-goog-meta-capture-ds": "2017-02-05T14:33:30.364112", "name": "0/02-05-2017/2017-02-05T14:33:30.364112.jpg"}
--===============5679188666781658153==
Content-Type: image/jpeg
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<Image Data>

--===============5679188666781658153==--
```

From my understanding I should be able to arbitrarily set metadata key:value pairs as long as the keys are prefixed with `x-goog-meta-*`.

Am I missing something? How can I persist the custom metadata to the object using a multipart upload?

Comment: Did you try with charset=UTF-8 instead of -charset="utf-8", and removing the initial MIME-Version?

Comment: @jarmod I didn't, I'm using the python `email.mime` utilities which adds the Version by default and I don't think I can remove it, although I don't think that is the issue. I assume that since it is correctly setting the object `name` that is defined in the same json that it is a problem with parsing the the metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this related question: [Google Storage API custom header on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378179/google-storage-api-custom-header-on-node-js)

As `jterrace` points out:

Take a look at the JSON request builder here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

You'll notice that metadata is a separate key in the body. So you'll want something like:

```
var metadata = {
    name: "name"
    contentLanguage: "en",
    metadata: {
      "something": "completely different",
    },
    acl: [...]
};
```